# Why does do.call drop rows from my list

Tags: r

I am working through the UFO example from the book "machine learning for hackers" and I have encountered a problem.

I have extracted a list of cities (cities.state) from the raw data and this is stored in a list with 61870 entries, each of which has 2 elements. i.e.

```
str(city.state)
List of 61870
$ : chr [1:2] "Iowa City" "IA"
$ : chr [1:2] "Milwaukee" "WI"
$ : chr [1:2] "Shelton" "WA"
```

I want to convert this list to a matrix, the approach which seems to be used in the book and here in other posts is use

```
do.call(rbind, city.state)
```

but when I run this I get a matrix of size 61591x2. This do.call appears to have dropped some rows from the original list, but I don't get any warnings in the r console.

Any ideas what is happening, and why do.call is dropping elements, or for alternatives to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Hard to tell without your data. One thing to check is to make sure none of the list entires are NULL.

Comment: If you mean this [file](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ML_for_Hackers/tree/master/01-Introduction/data/ufo), it has 61393 lines. Maybe you got it from another source? Or there was an error when reading the file, which would explain why you got errors afterwards.

Comment: I got the file from another source, that link does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was a combination of missing values and some values being coded as NA. To force do.call not to drop anything I add a row index to my list city.state using the following loop

```
for (i in 1:length(city.state)) {
  city.state[[i]] = c(city.state[[i]][1],city.state[[i]][2], i)
}
```

Now the following code does not drop any values

```
do.call(rbind, city.state)
```

Hope this helps others

Answer (score 1):

This reproduces the error. You should have some NULL entries in your list.

```
ll <- list(letters[1:2],letters[1:2],c(NULL,NULL))

str(ll)
List of 3
 $ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
 $ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
 $ : NULL

str(do.call(rbind,ll))
 chr [1:2, 1:2] "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

Try to remove NULL values:

```
ll[!unlist(lapply(ll,is.null))]
```